# Unable to read an apk file from an internal directory

Tags: android, apk, android-fileprovider

I'm downloading an apk from s3 and storing it in a directory named SAMPLE_APK. When I try to execute the apk present in the directory, I get an error.

```
2022-03-01 15:44:20.773 21867-21867/com.test.digitaloceanspaces D/Main Activity -: File 
path  - /data/user/0/com.test.digitaloceanspaces/app_SAMPLE_APK/debug.apk
2022-03-01 15:44:20.774 21867-21867/com.test.digitaloceanspaces D/AndroidRuntime: 
Shutting down VM  

--------- beginning of crash
2022-03-01 15:44:20.779 21867-21867/com.test.digitaloceanspaces E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.digitaloceanspaces, PID: 21867
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains 
/data/data/com.test.digitaloceanspaces/app_SAMPLE_APK/debug.apk
    at  
androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy
.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:800)
    at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:442)
```

But If I read the apk from filesDir, I'm able to execute it.

Below the two different directory structure

Unable to read the apk present in the file parameter of the callback method.

```
fun downloadLatestApk(callback: (File?, Exception?) -> Unit) {

//using a custom directory named sample apk
 val directoryName = "SAMPLE_APK"

    val directory = if (appContext.getDir(directoryName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).exists()) 
    {
        Log.d("Local directory", "APK directory Already exists")
        appContext.getDir(directoryName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    } else {
        Log.d("Local directory", "New Directory")
        File(appContext.filesDir, directoryName).apply {
            this.mkdir()
        }
    }

    val file = File(**directory**, "debug.apk")
    val listener = transferUtility.download(spacename, "debug.apk", file)

    listener.setTransferListener(object : TransferListener {

        override fun onStateChanged(id: Int, state: TransferState?) {
            if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                callback(file, null)
            }
        }
 }
```

Able to execute the apk present in the file parameter of the callback method. Here I'm reading the apk present in the filesDir.

```
fun downloadLatestAPk(callback: (File?, Exception?) -> Unit) {
//using files dir
val file = File(**appContext.filesDir**, "debug.apk")
    val listener = transferUtility.download(spacename, "debug.apk", file)

    listener.setTransferListener(object : TransferListener {

        override fun onStateChanged(id: Int, state: TransferState?) {
            if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                callback(file, null)
            }
        }
}
```

This happens only for apk. I'm able to read image files from either of the directories. Unable to fathom this behavior.

Folder structure - [Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svpDb.png)

The file provider has the following paths.

```
<paths>
<external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />

<external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />

<cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="." />

<external-cache-path
    name="external_cache"
    path="." />

<files-path
    name="files"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

File from the callback method is sent to the below method for execution.

```
private fun handleInstallation(file: File) {

    Log.d("Main Activity - ", "File path  - ${file.path}")

    val contentUri =
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            "com.test.digitaloceanspaces" + ".provider", file
        )

    val intent = Intent()
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
    intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

App crashes after printing the log statement.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: `When I try to run the apk by reading the directory,` One can not run an apk by reading a directory. Please reformulate what you want and do.

Comment: @blackapps Rephrased. It was my bad. Thanks.

Comment: Stil bad: `When I try to execute the apk present in the directory, I get an error.` You cannot execute an apk in a directory. And that is not what you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > path  - /data/user/0/com.test.digitaloceanspaces/app_SAMPLE_APK/debug.apk

That is a path not covered by FileProvider.

From `getFilesDir()` is covered by entry `<files-path`.

You could make it:

```
/data/user/0/com.test.digitaloceanspaces/files/app_SAMPLE_APK/debug.apk
```

Not covered by FileProvider: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains  /data/data/com.test.digitaloceanspaces/app_SAMPLE_APK/debug.apk`

> > Unable to read an apk file from an internal directory

No. Unable to use FileProvider for not allowed path.

Comment: File Path starting with /data/user/0/ is the absolute path and /data/data/package_name is the canonical path. I have mentioned 

 <files-path
        name="files"
        path="/"/> 

in the paths XML. Not sure why the file provider won't cover it  :(

Comment: Well that i told you in my answer. `That is a path not covered by FileProvider.` Please reread.

Comment: I understand that you wanted to have the directory under /files.  I also modified the code a bit. `/data/user/0/com.test.digitaloceanspaces/files/debug.apk`. This worked.

I'm able to locate an image file and set it to an image view using the below-mentioned file path.
`/data/user/0/com.test.digitaloceanspaces/app_SAMPLE_IMAGE/_smiley.jpg`.
My query was if it's able to find an image why not any other file format like .apk.

Comment: You use that path directly to set the file to an ImageView. That is perfectly ok. And you do that without using FileProvider. FileProvider cannot handle that path.

Comment: /data/user/0/com.test.digitaloceanspaces/files/SAMPLE_APK/debug.apk

This worked. Thanks for your support.